# Problem with IntelliSense during debugging in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

Why IntelliSense doesn't work when debugging in Visual Studio 2010?

When I am typing new code during debugging I am no getting any hints form Visual studio. Why is this so?

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't working"? While doing Edit&Continue? You know that IntelliSense is used for displaying variable contents while debugging, do you? Since you're not supposed to develop your application while debugging, regular IntelliSense is hardly needed.

Comment: @SirViver, I guess he is already referring to the intellisense popup that evaluates variables on the go.

Comment: I wanted regular IntelliSense to be available. Sometimes I see during debuging that I forgot to type some statement. And statements may be complicated to add it without IntelliSense on the fly. What is wrong with my arguments?

Comment: unfortunately that's not available while debugging, only the evaluator.

Comment: Thanks. Now, it is clear. I wonder why I've got downvotes for asking about feature which would be useful in some circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

You need to first break the execution with `Ctrl+Alt+Break` then you can use Intellisense if Edit & Continue feature is enabled.